# Can't run Node JS Deployment to Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I followed this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs

I've deployed an Express JS app using the "Zip Deploy" tool:

https://[app_name_here].scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeploy

When I try to call my public APIs, I keep getting an error saying "**The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**"

The weird thing is, my Express JS app runs just fine locally. I've tried changing my index.js several times to get my API routes exposed properly, but nothing seems to be working on Azure. Here is my current code.

It's admittedly a little disorganized/messy because I've been merging logic from 3 different Express apps.

...

*index.js*

```js
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');
app.use(cors({ origin:'*' }));
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);

//Router imports
var chainCoreDevRoutes = require('./routes/chainCoreDevRoutes');
var mongoDevRoutes = require('./routes/mongoDevRoutes');
var stuffMartServiceRoutes = require('./routes/stuffMartServiceRoutes');
app.use('/dev/chainCore', chainCoreDevRoutes);
app.use('/dev/mongo', mongoDevRoutes);
app.use('/api', stuffMartServiceRoutes);

//app.get('*', function(request, response) { response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html')); });

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running wubbalubba dub dub! on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

...

*routes/index.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

...

*web.config (needed for Azure environment)*

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <!-- indicates that the index.js file is a node.js application 
        to be handled by the iisnode module -->

        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>

        <!-- adds index.js to the default document list to allow 
        URLs that only specify the application root location, 
        e.g. http://mysite.antarescloud.com/ -->

        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <add value="index.js" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>

      </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution:
**Do not follow the tutorials/blogposts**

I used Visual Studio 2017, and found a project template called "Basic Azure Node.js Express 4 App". The base project worked swimmingly, and it only took like 5 minutes to setup.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for deployments of nodejs is by using the terminal.

You simply clone the project to the server as you would do in normal machine.
Do "npm install"
Run the project by "npm start" or "node index.js"(It depends according to your file name).
The check whether the program gets up in the server,You would better use postman to test whether api's are working.
If there are bugs fix them.
If not install pm2 to the server machine.
Then start the program using "pm2 index.js" (Accordingly).

Every time you make differences to the code,it is good to type "pm2 restart all" to apply changes

Answer (score 0):

I used express generate to create my simple project, then deploy it to azure successfully. Please refer to my files.

***app.js***

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

console.log("+++++++++++++++"+ app.get('port'));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
          console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
          });
```

***web.config***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

***routes/index.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

***Access Result:***

[image]

You could check the differences.Any concern, please let me know.

Comment: I followed the tutorial I listed in the question, which builds off of the Express Generator. 
I actually solved the problem by avoiding tutorials. I found a template in Visual Studio 2017, it was called something like "Basic Node.js Express 4 App". The base template worked perfectly.